# Mediaelement.js, using API to time animation to audio

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to play some jQuery animations based on where I am in the audio track. I need to match lots of 'flying letters' to audio voice tracks (sort of Flash/Powerpoint style).

I am using mediaelement.js:  http://mediaelementjs.com/

How would I go about timing animation to audio?  In my Fiddle, they both run, but they aren't tied together.  Thus if the audio loads slowly, the animation will be out of sync.  Or vice versa.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/x4t9Z/3/

Maybe I could use currentTime (get) or progress() from the mediaelement API, but I always get undefined for value.

```
    function fadein() {

    //var audiotime = player.currentTime(get);
    //alert (audiotime);

    var t = $('.activeslide').find('.animated').data('times');
    if (t) {
        $('.animated').find('.fadein').hide();
        var anima = $('.activeslide').find('.animated').find('.fadein');
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                 anima.eq(i).delay(t[i]).fadeIn(220);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope I'm not late at the party :) , [here you go [fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/girish2040/HJCfT/)

What you can do is

```
(function ($) {
    $('.fadein').hide();

    //player
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player', {
        pauseOtherPlayers: true,
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            var lastUpdatedT = 0;
            mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function (e) {
            }, false);

            mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {

                if (mediaElement.paused) return;

                if (typeof fadein == "function") {
                    var currentT = Math.floor(mediaElement.currentTime);

                    if (!(currentT == lastUpdatedT)) {
                        fadein(currentT);
                        lastUpdatedT = currentT;
                    }
                }
            }, false);

            // call the play method
            mediaElement.play();
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
    player.pause();
    player.play();


    //animation
    function fadein(time) {
        var t = $('.activeslide').find('.animated').data('times');
        var cIndex = $.inArray(time, t);

        if (cIndex >= 0) {
            //Uncomment below if you want to show animation in same single line or you can also have a fade out time array
            //$('.animated').find('.fadein').hide();
            var anima = $('.activeslide').find('.animated').find('.fadein');
            anima.eq(cIndex).show();
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It's super, girish!  If you go to the http://mediaelementjs.com/, Can you also make this work with ie8 ?  I think it's loading Flash or Silverlight in ie8.  I have a bad problem with ie8, crashes my party. -- If you can make it work with the "seek" button too, then you should post it as a plugin!